# checking a string for null in java

Tags: java, string

I have this:

```
String object = "";
try {
    object = data.getString("url");
    System.out.println("Url Object:" + object);
}
catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}  

System.out.println("object is:" + object);
if (object!= null ) {
    // doSomething
} else {
    // is Null
}
```

and although this is printed:

```
object is: null
```

The code enters the if condition and not the else.

What am I missing?

EDIT: where data is a JSONObject. I now want to test the case that url is null. Therefore, I know that data is null and I can see it printed.

Comment: Perhaps you have `String object = "null";` higher up?

Comment: We can't say anything with the code you provide. Could you show a small program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Can you show what is `object`?

Comment: Also, I don't believe that's the code that corresponds to your output (note the missing `:`).  Please always post *real* code and *real* output.

Comment: Provide code, or else we can't help you.

Comment: Now where is the code where you create `data`? What is the output of `System.out.println("Url Object:" + object);`?

Comment: Even if `!= null` should work, you can try out calling `Object`'s `equals()` method.

`if(!object.equals(null))`

Comment: change your top line to `String object;`

Comment: @Check my edit. No I am not setting it to null, and yes it is real code, I just didn't paste the log from the console and wrote it manually.

Comment: Do you get `Url Object: null`?

Comment: :'( Why not post MVCE. You are using `data` and I have no idea what is its type, what library is the `JSONException`.

Comment: Try: `if (object!= null ) { System.out.println(object.getClass().getName();}`  // if it says String... that is the problem, it is "null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that `getString(..)` is returning `"null"` (as a `String`, when `ob.toString()` do that). So when you assign it to `object`, it is a `String: "null"`, not `null`.

To correct your code one way would be:

```
if (!object.equals("null")) {
   // doSomething
} else {
   // is Null
}
```

Another solution would be setting `object` to be `null` if `getString()` returns `"null"`:

```
if (data.getString("url").equals("null"))
    object = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is an anti pattern. Move the code that processes 'string' inside the 'try' block. Don't just catch exceptions and then continue as though they didn't happen, and have to sort out *again* whether you're in a valid state. That's what the 'try' block is for. If you're still in it, you're in a valid state.

Answer (score 1):

Don't initialize your `String object` to `""` if you want it to be `null` if the json parsing bits fail.

Change your top line to:

`String object = null;`

More to the point, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/21246501/599075

Comment: That should give you a variable might not be initialized type error if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: It should be initialtied though because otherwise it does not compile

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation to your case is that the `data.getString("url");` is returning a "null" String value.By the way I recommend you these points :

- Initialize your object by a null reference (`String object = null;`)
- Change the `if` condition (`if(object!=null) && !object.isEmpty()`)

  Otherwise, try to print entirely the content of the `data` object to the console so you can check the json content you are trying to parse.
  (Sorry if I made some language mistakes)